# Non-uniform property of sequences

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let us say a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in some Banach space $X$ has $S_C$ if there exist $k_1<k_2<\ldots$ such that for any $t\in \mathbb{N}$ and scalars $(a_n)_{n=1}^t$, $$\|\sum_{n=1}^t a_n x_{k_n}\|\leqslant C\Bigl(\sum_{n=1}^t |a_n|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}.$$

Let us say the Banach space $X$ has $HSP$ if every normalized, weakly null sequence in $X$ has $S_C$ for some $C>0$.

For $C>0$, let us say the Banach space $X$ has $C$-$HSP$ if every normalized, weakly null sequence in $X$ has $S_C$.

Is there a reflexive Banach space $X$ such that $X$ has $HSP$ but for each $C>0$, $X$ fails $C$-$HSP$?

Comment: Did you try to consider the direct sum in 2-norm of reflexive spaces with the C_n - HSP , attaining C_n, with C_n tending to infinity?

Comment: Yes. Suppose that $\sup_n C_n=\infty$ and for each $n$, $(x^n_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is a normalized weakly null sequence which has a $C_n+1$ upper $\ell_2$ estimate but has no subsequence with a $C_n$ upper $\ell_2$ estimate. Suppose also that $(x^n_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ lies in a subspace $E_n$ of $X$ such that there exist uniformly bounded projections $P_n:X\to E_n$ such that $E_m\subset \ker(P_n)$ for all $m\neq n$. Then, after passing to a subsequence to assume $(C_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/\sqrt{C_n}<1$.

Comment: Then we can let $w_n=1/\sqrt{C_n}$ and $x_i=\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n x^n_i$. If $b=\sup_n \|P_n\|$, then $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty\subset B_X$ and for each $n$, we can show that no subsequence has a $w_nC_n/b$ upper $\ell_2$ estimate. Since $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty\subset B_X$ is weakly null, this shows that $X$ cannot have $HSP$. 

At the moment, without the assumption that we can project from $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ onto $(w_nx^n_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ by $P_n$, I cannot see how to show that $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ does not have good $\ell_2$ upper estimates.

Comment: ok I agree with you. Your question reminds me of a recent result I have with Pavlos Motakis that there exists a reflexive Banach space with unique $\ell_1$ spreading model but no subspace with a uniformly unique $\ell_1$ spreading model. Probably a 2-convexification of that example could lead to a strong answer to your question. The paper is posted to arXiv.

Comment: When I say that "I agree with you" I think that it is clear. I also agree with the last remark made by "user 19871987". Hence it is not clear to me what is the answer. The paper I mentioned is that quoted by "LSpice"

Comment: @user19871987 I had a similar scheme in mind but also couldn't make it work yet. However it makes me wonder if you have a non-reflexive example.

Comment: I don't have a non-reflexive example. However, I wanted to know the answer to this question as part of a broader line of questioning. It is in that context that reflexivity is important. However, just out of curiosity, I would be interested in a non-reflexive example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and the reflexivity plays no role. This is actually a theorem of [Knaust and Odell](http://helmut.knaust.info/paper/KOulp.pdf).

Comment: I have also found that Freeman generalized this to any normalized basic sequence. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.0218.pdf